# API access authentication java

Tags: java, authentication, google-api

I would like to implement an utility to perform background operation with Google APIs (e.g. Calendar API).
The utility has no user interface so I need to perform all the authentication flow server-side.
Any java suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start here:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

That should give you general high level info for server to server calls for authorization. Then read up on the Java client here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2

You should be able to piece things together with those two sets of information. Good luck.

Comment: I modified the question with give more details.

Comment: It seems like this is now a new question.  Not really sure that warranted removing the `accept` on the answer.  Probably should have just been a new question.

Comment: You right, I creat a new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670032/google-calendar-api-server-side-access