# Google Calendar API server side access

Tags: java, events, google-calendar-api

I implemented an utility to perform background operation using Google Calendar API and server side authentication flow without user interface.
Now I would like to read events from a private calendar without using authorization flow with offline access or put calendar public.

I'm using this code for authentication:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(SchedulerCalendar.HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(SchedulerCalendar.JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(SchedulerCalendar.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(SchedulerCalendar.SCOPES)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12")).build();
```

And the following for read calendar events:

```
List eventslist = calendar.events().list(calendarid);
```

The response is 404 for calendar not found.

Any suggestion?

Comment: How are you creating your `Calendar` instance?  Can you add the code that shows that part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem sharing the calendar to the *@developer.gserviceaccount.com,
and I added http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/ to scope of the request.

The calendar that I'm using is also from a google apps user so I add also my account *.apps.googleusercontent.com  -> http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/ to Manage API client access from google apps control panel.